# "T'en as un œil" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

I encountered this while reading *Astérix*. The exchange is as follows, where the druid is a prisoner in a Gothic jail being threatened by his captors who are demanding to see his magic:

> Goth: Accepte de montrer ta magie, druide ! Je te couvrirai d'or !
>   Druide: T'en as un œil !

I'm guessing it's some snappy retort to the effect of "shove it up your #%^&", but I'm not sure what the actual expression is here. *En avoir un œil* ? When can this be used? What is the exact meaning?

Comment: Je n'ai plus le contexte en tête mais je pense qu'il faut comprendre comme  [(bon) oeil](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/41685).

Comment: Check out my comment under Mistalis post.

Answer (score 1):

Like many jokes found in *Astérix*, *t'en as un œil !* is likely a *double entendre* expression primarily meaning here :

> *Tu en as du [toupet](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toupet) !*
>
> *Quel [culot](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/culot) !*

and possibly :

> *En voilà un peu !*
>
> *Tu as la vue perçante !* (you have a good eye!)

In modern vulgar French, a similar reply for the first meaning would be

> *Mon cul !* (My ass!)

but that would be too trivial from Panoramix.

*Œil* used to be slang for "ass" (arse) leading to many jokes. That very same slang "eye" is suspected to be the origin of the expression *se mettre le doigt dans l'œil*…

Comment: C'est tout? Je veux dire, il n'y a pas un jeu de mot, ou quelque chose de plus dans cette situation dans Astérix et d'Obélix?

Comment: Je ne ferai plus jamais de clin d’œil.

Comment: @Frank Il y a souvent des jeux de mots à double sens dans Astérix. Il est possible que le légionnaire ait aussi quelque chose à l'œil.

Comment: Oui. J'ai aussi une interprétation dans ma réponse.

Comment: @Frank Oui, c'est bien possible. Après un peu de recherche, il est clair que l'expression avait déjà plusieurs sens à l'époque où elle était utilisée, essentiellement au début du XXe siècle.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps what do you mean? "I will never wink"? What?

Comment: @Aerovistae now that I've realized that *œil* is often a metaphor for the butthole.

Answer (score 1):

## Contexte

Cette réplique vient d'*Astérix et les Goths, page 29* où Panoramix a été capturé par les Goths voulant de la potion magique.

Cloridric est le seul goth pouvant parler français. Sous la pression de son chef (insistant pour avoir de la potion magique), il dit à Panoramix :

*Cloridric : - Accepte de montrer ta magie [...] je te couvrirai d'or.*

*Panoramix : - T'en as un œil !*

<sub>Après plusieurs relectures, et pour répondre au commentaire de [*@Frank*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25146/13109), je n'ai pas vu de jeu de mot dans ce paragraphe justifiant cette expression.</sub>

---

## Explanation

Panoramix knows perfectly well that Cloridric **can not** "cover him with gold": he is only an interpreter and has no money.

You can understand this sentence as irony, **Panoramix shows that he knows that the Gothic is a liar**.

---

## Expressions synonymes

Formel :

> *- Tu te moques de moi !*

Langage parlé, courant :

> *- Mais bien sûr !* (ironie)
>
> *- Ben, voyons !*
>
> *- Oui oui ...* (ironie)

Argot, vulgaire :

> *- Et mon cul, c'est du poulet ?!*

Comment: Could it possibly be a play on words with something in German?

Comment: I know! Maybe it is the expression "avoir l'oeil" meaning knowing how to eyeball/measure things: the druid being tall, the Goth cannot evaluate properly how much gold would be required.

Answer (score 1):

According to the context explained by Mistalis, where the Goth just told Panoramix:

> Cloridric : - Accepte de montrer ta magie [...] je te couvrirai d'or.

it could be the expression *avoir l’œil*, meaning knowing how to eyeball/measure things: the druid being tall, the Goth cannot evaluate properly how much gold would be required, and Panoramix is just commenting on that.